QMediaPlayer speeding up a video after pausing and resuming the video on a Raspberry Pi 5
So, I started testing an Raspberry Pi 5 with the same code I used on a Raspberry Pi 4 previously. In my code it has an video player that u can play the video and pause whenever you want, but when I pause the video, it just speeds up the video, and that didn't happened when I was using the 4 version
I'm using the gstreamer since the ffmpeg doesn't have the backend to support PySide6 QMediaPlayer. So I'm using the command 'export QT_MEDIA_BACKEND=gstreamer'
And there is my code:
import sys
import time
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl, QTimer
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QAudioOutput
from PySide6.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel

class VideoPlayer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer()
        self.audioOutput = QAudioOutput()
        self.mediaPlayer.setAudioOutput(self.audioOutput)

        videoWidget = QVideoWidget()

        playButton = QPushButton("Play/Pause")
        playButton.clicked.connect(self.play_video)

        self.statusLabel = QLabel()
        self.timeLabel = QLabel()
        self.frameDropLabel = QLabel()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(videoWidget)
        layout.addWidget(playButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.statusLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.timeLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.frameDropLabel)

        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)

        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile("/home/gabriel/Desktop/Recicle/recicle/VIdeo/output1.mp4"))
        self.mediaPlayer.errorOccurred.connect(self.handle_error)
        self.mediaPlayer.playbackStateChanged.connect(self.update_status)
        self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.update_position)

        self.startTime = 0
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_time)

    def play_video(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.playbackState() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
            self.pauseTime = time.time()
            self.timer.stop()
            print("Paused at:", self.mediaPlayer.position() / 1000.0, "seconds")
        else:
            if self.mediaPlayer.playbackState() == QMediaPlayer.PausedState:
                paused_duration = time.time() - self.pauseTime
                self.startTime += paused_duration
            self.mediaPlayer.play()
            if self.startTime == 0:
                self.startTime = time.time()
            self.timer.start(1000)  # Update every second
            print("Resumed at:", self.mediaPlayer.position() / 1000.0, "seconds")

    def handle_error(self, error):
        self.statusLabel.setText(f"Error: {self.mediaPlayer.errorString()}")
        print(f"Error: {self.mediaPlayer.errorString()}")

    def update_status(self, state):
        states = {
            QMediaPlayer.StoppedState: "Stopped",
            QMediaPlayer.PlayingState: "Playing",
            QMediaPlayer.PausedState: "Paused"
        }
        self.statusLabel.setText(f"State: {states.get(state, 'Unknown')}")
        print(f"State: {states.get(state, 'Unknown')}")
        if state == QMediaPlayer.StoppedState:
            self.timer.stop()
        elif state == QMediaPlayer.PausedState:
            self.pauseTime = time.time()

    def update_position(self, position):
        elapsed_time = time.time() - self.startTime
        actual_time = position / 1000
        self.timeLabel.setText(f"Expected Time: {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds, Actual Time: {actual_time:.2f} seconds")
        print(f"Expected Time: {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds, Actual Time: {actual_time:.2f} seconds")
        if abs(elapsed_time - actual_time) > 1:
            self.frameDropLabel.setText("Warning: Frame drop detected!")
            print("Warning: Frame drop detected!")

    def update_time(self):
        elapsed_time = time.time() - self.startTime
        self.timeLabel.setText(f"Elapsed Time: {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = VideoPlayer()
    player.resize(640, 480)
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

I tried to update the libraries of gstreamer but it's already at the newest version, I tried to format my SD card but it continues with the same problem. And I tried to search for everything on forums but no one had this problem before, if anyone would happen to know something I would be deeply grateful.

Did you use the same configuration (Qt version, python binding, gstreamer version) in the old Rpi? Did you try other files (possibly with different codecs and resolutions)? Did you try to play the video(s) with another player that uses gstreamer? What do you mean by "ffmpeg doesn't have the backend to support PySide6 QMediaPlayer"?

Yes, I tried all this options and it still happens to do the same problem, it's the same qt, python and gstreamer versions.
About the ffmpeg doesn't having backend, it shows this when you try to start some video with the ffmpeg backend:
No QtMultimedia backends found. Only QMediaDevices, QAudioDevice, QSoundEffect, QAudioSink, and QAudioSource are available.
Failed to initialize QMediaPlayer "Not available"
Failed to create QVideoSink "Not available"

Then it's actually the other way around: ffmpeg doesn't have any "Qt backend", it's Qt that eventually has/use an ffmpeg one. In theory, on Linux it should be able to work with the installed one (but that may also depend on the Qt build, it's possible that the one you're using, provided by the package manager, isn't configured to use ffmpeg). Have you tried to force the backend by using export QT_MEDIA_BACKEND=ffmpeg? You didn't answer about using another gstreamer based player: if the problem also happens there, then it's a gstreamer issue, and Qt can do nothing about it.

I tried to use this command:
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///home/gabriel/Desktop/Recicle/recicle/VIdeo/output1.mp4
and used this to pause and unpause in another terminal:
kill -SIGSTOP 
sleep 2  # Pausa por 2 segundos
kill -SIGCONT 
and it doesn't speed ups the video.
About forcing the ffmpeg, I used it before and just switches to ffmpeg. Still does the same problem.

I got it to work, it's a problem on the 6.7.2 version for some reason, I revert to version 6.7.1 and it works perfectly.
